# Question and answer by same user

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

A Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) looks to be asked by the same user and answered / approved by himself.

I thought one of two things could have happened.

1. The user replied to his own question after figuring out the answer (common occurence). But the time stamps for both the question and answer are identical indicating he already knew the answer.
2. Another user asked the question, and may have deleted his profile. I am not sure how SO handles the situation. Would the question move over to the editor of the question ? Again the time stamps of the question and answer are identical so this does not seem likely either.

Is it a bug ? If not is this behavior considered constructive ? In this particular case, it was not a bad question, it is not a bad answer. But is there an alternative way to dispense knowledge ?

Comment: [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/187824)

Comment: @hims056 Thanks. I tried looking through the suggested list. May be it was my wording, but this question did not show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the user posted the answer *along with* his question, at the *exact same time*. It's one of the features of the site - you can type your answer while you're typing your question and submit them both at once. It's called instant self-answer. Likely he just wanted to share his knowledge from his experience with the problem he was facing and has now solved with the rest of the world.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen a scenario like this before. I tried to see if similar questions were asked, but the suggestions did not show anything. It may be the way I phrased the question.